# Which tool can show the maximum statements of Method or function in C++?

Tags: c++, metrics

our project is really big. the source codes size is about 620KLOC in one module. So I want to check which function is the biggest in a directory/module?  Is there any tool can support it?

SourceMonitor only has "Average Statements per Method", not maximum statements per method.
CCCC doesn't support it either.

example. This function length is 1.

```
unsigned short get()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I doubt if this is possible with current tools.

Comment: Clang offers neat infrastructure for writing various source-level tools. You can use it to develop your own tool.

Comment: it would vary if you are using optimizations

Comment: To arrowdodger: Clang is too complex for me. Is there any existed tool to support max method metrics?

Answer (score 2):

The *easiest* thing I can think of is scripting your way through it.

- Use e.g [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) to get a list of functions in the file
- Use perl/python/awk/grep to split your source file into separate files,
  one file per function
- Simply count the lines of each file, take the maximum length.
  If you need more details, feed each file into a loc-counter e.g. [sloccount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/) to
  get more refined information. Use grep again to get the output you are 
  interested in

Another tool that might be of help:

Lazy C++: Is is a code generator that splits files that are very similar to c++ into header and source. If you write you transform your code into a lzz file the generated code includes line counter tags per function. The differences in those numbers would show you how big your functions are

Comment: instead of splitting into different files, I would recommend using ctags with -x, in the human readable output line number are given. sort by them, and its easy to compute the lines (that number is just approx., but should be enough to find the biggest) per function

Comment: I didn't use ctags before. I'll look the introduce and try to understand it.

Comment: ctage seams really powerful. Flolo and Martin, are you familiar with it? can you give the commands to support my requirements? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can scan your project with our [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/) tool, and for your needs it provides CSV files containing functions/methods with metrics (among others size metrics you are looking for) and also the containing module (e.g. library, shared object, executable). Using a spreadsheet editor you can easily find the biggest functions/methods per module.

Answer (score 0):

I think that many static analysis tools may not give you what you need since they don't necessarily take into account things like template instantiations, header inclusions (including those pulled in by precompiled headers) and the code generation characteristics of the compiler.

I've faced a similar problem in the past, with a large executable whose size was dominated by a particular library.  The way I got to the bottom of it was simply to look at the size of the object files for each .cpp. That won't give you the full story as the linker will optimise out unused portions (though it's worth checking you've got that option set - `/OPT:REF` for Visual Studio).  It will though allow you to focus your search.  Find the two or three largest object files and then look at the corresponding .cpp files.  You've then got two options - write a script that takes the output of `objdump` (VisualStudio) or `nm -C` (gcc) where you can extract the offsets of each function in the module, so you can diff each with the previous to get an idea of the size of each function.

Or the simplest method is just to use binary search on the cpp file.  #ifdef out all the code after the end of the #includes and compile it. That will give you an idea of the overhead of the includes (if that itself is huge then you can drill down into the header inclusions to find which contributes the most).  Next, disable each half the code with #ifdef and find which half is the larger.  Using this method you can quickly find the functions that contribute most to the size of the library.

In the case of the library I had which had this same problem, the cause turned out to be a very large templated function that was instantiated every time a member variable was saved.  The solution in that case was to make the function concrete so that all the code that didn't require type-specific behaviour is only instantiated once, and the template functions are localised for the bits of logic that are type-specific.

Comment: Static analysis tools is enough for me. We can ignore template codes because of our template codes are small. Some of our "normal" C++ methods are more than 600 code lines.  And I don't think object file size can get the method code lines except one file has one method. But it's not true for us.

Answer (score 0):

[CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) give you this info, it's based on Clang and with CQLinq you can request your code as you want.